# What is the relation between "Capital Market Line" and "Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM)"?

Tags: markets, capital

<sub>I asked this question on [Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/posts/141763/edit) but was asked to ask it here.</sub>

On the Coursera course [Portfolio and Risk Management, on Week 2](https://www.coursera.org/learn/portfolio-risk-management/home/week/2), I am having trouble finding the link between the following 2 formulas from the following 2 slides:

| Formula 1 | Formula 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: The Capital Market Line] | [image: Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM)] |
| From video [Capital market equilibrium - The Capital Market Line](https://www.coursera.org/learn/portfolio-risk-management/lecture/svT8r/capital-market-equilibrium-the-capital-market-line) | From video [Capital market equilibrium - The Capital Asset Pricing Model](https://www.coursera.org/learn/portfolio-risk-management/lecture/xftSO/capital-market-equilibrium-the-capital-asset-pricing-model) |

From the slides above my conclusion would be the following equation:

$$
\beta_i = \frac{cov(R_i,R_M)}{var(R_M)} = \frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_M}
$$

So I have the following doubts:

1. Is this right?
2. How do you get from one expression to the other?
3. In *Formula 2*, the expression for $\beta$ includes a relation between the asset and the market. But in *Formula 1* the relation $\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_M}$ suggest there is no relation between the market and the asset. 
   Why is this?

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65613/54838